# Elastic search 2.3 query issue

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

I am doing a query on data in python,

When I just do a match and sort it works fine.

```
res = es.search( body={"size" : 100, 
                "query": {"match": {"SensorId": "f0038c53272a"}},
                "sort":{"StartDateTime": "desc"}})
```

Now when I introduce range, it starts giving an error

```
res = es.search( body={"size" : 100, 
       "query": {"match": {"SensorId": "f0038c53272a"}},
       "sort":{"StartDateTime": "desc"},
       "range":{"StartDateTime":{"gte":"now-50d/d","lt": "now/d"}}})
```

The error it throws is

```
 elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: 
 TransportError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 
 'No mapping found for [StartDateTime] in order to sort on')
```

Elasticsearch version is 2.3. Any clue would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error is usually caused by the field not being in the mapping, i.e. there is no document with that field. Check if the index is empty or there is any typo in the field name.

Furthermore the syntax of the filter is incorrect. See [filter context](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/query-filter-context.html#query-filter-context) or [post filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/search-request-post-filter.html#search-request-post-filter). Here is the query with the former:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {"match": {"SensorId": "f0038c53272a"}},
      "filter": {"range": {"StartDateTime": {"gte": "now-50d/d", "lt": "now/d"}}}
    }
  },
  "sort":{"StartDateTime": "desc"}
}
```

If the check on `SensorId` is an exact match and doesn't really need any scoring you may want to further optimize the query moving the match in the filter too.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could also be in the date range format. Trying given "gte": "now-50d/d", "lt": "now/d" may not work. In our case the time in the column was in POSIX format, so like a 'long' number. In that case you can try specifying date range as:

```
 {"range": {"StartDateTime": {"gte": "1531108114", "lt": "1531280914"}}}
```